# Why WiFi modules can't listen to remote HTTP requests?

Tags: wireless, wifi

I can see that `ATMEL` has this WiFi module -  [ATWINC1500](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42502-SmartConnect-WINC1500-MR210PB_Datasheet.pdf). I know that modules such as the `ESP8266` are not capable to **listen** to requests outside the network ( which means I am not at home and I want to control it from my iPhone).

I am trying to understand what **keyword** should I look for in the data sheet, to understand if I can set it as a station that listen to HTTP requests all the time.

Why for example with `ESP` you have to set a **port forwarding** to do this, and when you buy a smart coffee machine it can be done without any hassle ? what is the difference in the hardware that enables these companies to make smart device that are accssesible without all this port forwarding dirty technical hassle ?
How is that my computer is accessible from anywhere and these modules are not?

Comment: It depends on how you program it. Its just a wifi module, if you have a tcp/ip stack with full http server running constantly on it there is no reason it can't serve http requests.

Comment: A Wifi module by itself (no **application** software running on it) doesn't **care** about HTTP, a Wifi module cannot even "see" if you're doing HTTP, FTP, SSH or whatever. That's because a WiFi module concerns itself with the **connection** and not the **data** being transported over that connection. To understand this better, familiarize yourself with the OSI model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model and see how it is layered. The Wifi module is part of the one or 2 bottom layers. HTTP is much higher up (layer 5 if I'm  not mistaking).

Comment: To listen to HTTP requests you need: an IP Address, a TCP/IP Stack and an HTTP Server. To implement an HTTP server, you need a fair amount of ROM and RAM. The TCP/IP stack is already integrated in the ESP8266. It should be possible to implement an HTTP server with the ESP8266. But maybe you are mixing things up, if you want to control it from outside of your home (over the Internet) you need access to your public IP address and set up some sort of port forwarding to get external request to your internal HTTP server.

Comment: @Arsenal exactly! you need a port forwarding, and this is what I am missing here. How is that some IoT products enables you to control them from afar without any port forwarding ? when you buy a smart coffee machine as a non tech guy you don't do these things and yet you can control it from work. How ? whats the difference in the hardware ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache thanks I am reading this, but please take a look at the editing question regarding the port forwarding

Comment: Because port forwarding can be a hassle to setup, these products don't use that ! Instead they connect to the manufacturer's server. So the connection is initiated from the client side, the client logs in, the data connection is present and the server can communicate with the client.

Comment: So they are doing pooling to their server ? or do  they passively listen ?

Comment: I can easily send informtation from these modules, or ask a server for a data every second, but this seems to be very stupid, you have to a server every second if somebody wants something, its extremely slowlyIs there another way to actually listen to incoming comm ?

Comment: Think about it, once the server knows how to reach the client it only needs to listen and perhaps keep the connection alive. Only after connection lost due to power off for example, a new connection must be established.

Comment: yea but then you have to ask the remote server every 100ms if somebody wants something, is that the way to remote control things? its slowly and takes a lot of power ( ? )

Comment: *you have to a server every second if somebody wants something* No, once the connection (session) is established the client only needs to listen while keeping the session open. It's like a webpage with something which updates every few minutes like a weather map for example. Once the session is active the server just sends the new data whenever available. The client might only need to confirm that it has received the data.

Comment: Remember that the _S_ in _IoT_ stands for Security. Now, this has turned into a pretty off-topic question, it seems.

Comment: Oh I see ok thanks a lot, so you basically must have the middle server, its not direct in any way , their devices always connected to a server and gets HTTP. Thanks :)

Comment: *You have to ask the remote server every 100ms if somebody wants something* No you still don't get it. Once the session is opened no data needs to be send. It depends on the application how you can solve this. You will need to dive deeper into how this is done because it is done.

Comment: I got it, I was thinking the hardware has some kind of way to directly get commands from anyone who knows its IP. So today the only way to be able to directly control something from anywhere, is GSM ? Post it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GSM vs Wifi?

Answer (score 4):

This is not going to be a complete answer, because this whole issue dominates IoT development and is too big to fit here. Instead it's going to be a list of places to start finding the solutions. Put words in bold into your search engine.

The key issue is **NAT**. This normally makes it impossible to initiate connections into an end-user network, only outbound connections are possible. UDP is supported via "pseudo-connections" which must pass a certain amount of traffic to be kept open. NAT is widely deployed due to **shortage of IPV4 addresses**.

NAT may apply to Wifi (for devices on consumer premises) or GSM. It's very rare to get a GSM network configured to allow inbound TCP with public IP addresses.

So there are various workarounds. **HTTP long polling**, where the device connects to a server and leaves the connection open. Systems for opening ports through NAT such as **STUN** and **UPnP**.

Lots of IoT systems seem to use **MQTT**, which wraps some of this stuff up for you.

Another alternative is to deploy **IPv6** and get your devices proper publicly routable IPv6 addresses to which inbound connections can be made. However this depends on getting your clients to upgrade their networks.

It's worth looking for **teardown** or **reverse engineering** of existing devices, such as a [coffee machine](https://www.evilsocket.net/2016/10/09/IoCOFFEE-Reversing-the-Smarter-Coffee-IoT-machine-protocol-to-make-coffee-using-terminal/) (LAN only, not available from work - so it doesn't address the inbound connection issue of your question at all) or [lightbulbs](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/40397.html) (disastrously insecure).